# Load imagem of entity in zend form

Tags: php, image, zend-framework2, doctrine, zend-form

Icons have a manager, it was already providing all the crud.
However I have a problem, when you open the form, a Zend Form to edit an icon can not load the image that is already saved.

I am using the following element:

```
$element = new Image();
$element->setName('my-image')
        ->setAttribute('src', '/assets/no_image.png')
        ->setAttribute('id', 'my-image')
        ->setAttribute('height', '96')
        ->setAttribute('width', '96')
        ->setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
$this->add($element);
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: What output do you get? Also, this is really not what the image form element is for.

Comment: So, as I did not know what actually use I put this element. The image is the src attribute is always displayed, never the entity being edited.